# Netbeans - add JAR module

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, jar

I have downloaded module for Eclipse in JAR formate, but I am developing in Netbeans, which accepts only NBM module files. Do you know how to convert JAR to NBM? Have you been facing the same issue?

Thanks for reply

Waypoint

Comment: Huh?  Eclipse certainly accepts JAR files - both for Java projects within Eclipse, as well as plugins for Eclipse itself.  I'm not really familiar with NetBeans or NBM files, though.  Did you mean to say you're looking to convert NBM files to JAR files (the reverse of what you have written) for use with Eclipse?

Comment: Sry, I had a typo. I am developing in NetBeans and I have got JAR plugin for Eclipse. I want to know, how to convert JAR module (initialy for eclipse) to NBM module for NetBeans

Comment: Which is this module for Eclipse? Haven't you found the corresponding NetBeans plugin?

Comment: Nope, it is ArcGIS Runtime API plugin, which is available only for Eclipse in the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to run an Eclipse Plugin in NetBeans. Simply "converting" the jar to an nbm would not suffice as these, NetBeans and Eclipse, are two totally different programs. Furthermore, Eclipse uses a completely different UI (SWT) than NetBeans (Swing) and these two systems are not compatible.

The only way to use a plugin designed for Eclipse in NetBeans is to port the plugin to NetBeans. To do this you would need the source code and a good understanding of both NetBeans and the plugin you intend to port.

FYI: An nbm is little more than a compressed file (like a jar) that includes it's own MANIFEST file and the jar file which holds the code for the plugin. It's sort of a jar that holds a jar. You can see what's in an nbm by using something like 7-Zip to extract the contents (as you can do with a jar).